# Rangy | How to remove highlighted text with click event on span tag?

Tags: javascript, rangy

As the `rangy library` says that, we need to select `text` to make it highlight and remove highlight.

For highlighting it includes `span tag`.

For removing highlight text I want to click on `span tag` instead of select that text.

this is `library` method is used to remove highlight:

```
 unhighlightSelection: function(selection) {
                selection = selection || api.getSelection();
                console.log(selection.getAllRanges())
                var intersectingHighlights = this.getIntersectingHighlights( selection.getAllRanges() );
                this.removeHighlights(intersectingHighlights);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                return intersectingHighlights;
            }
```

here `selection` variable occupied with `api.getSelection()` instead of `local selection variable`.

I think it's sufficient to all of you to understand my problem.

I can give more description about that if you want.

Can I do something that to occupied the `selection variable` same as `api.getSelection()` without using it?

or what I do to achieve it?

Any suggestion will be grateful for me.

***Thank you***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is to be able to click on a highlight to get rid of it, I suggest something like the following (which has support for IE 6-8; I don't know whether you need that but Rangy supports it). The crucial methods are the `getHighlightForElement()` and `removeHighlights()`:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var highlight = highlighter.getHighlightForElement(target);
    if (highlight) {
        highlighter.removeHighlights( [highlight] );
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work. (I'm using version 1.3.0)